# Вопрос от новичка по js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Делаю корзину для интернет магазина, при нажатии на кнопку для открытия корзины, выполняется ajax запрос и выводятся div контейнеры (для каждого товара), в каждом контейнере есть, например, кнопка удаления товара из корзины, имеющая определённый css класс, на который повешен обработчик, который берёт id этой кнопки, вырезает начало, например "tovarDelete_", а дальше при генерации блоков этих товаров, был вписан номер товара, прям в css атрибут id. После работы с этой строчкой, полученный id с соответствующей командой отправляется на сервер.
Как я понимаю это ужасный способ работы. Подскажите, как правильно делаются подобные вещи!
Может при открытии корзины надо создавать объект для каждого товара, но тогда как записать в этот объект ссылку на тот же элемент его удаления?

```
    $('#conteyner_div').on('click', '.vkorzinu', function(){

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id.substr(14, id.length);

    inBasket(id);

});
```

Вот, к примеру, получение id товара.

Comment: я только хотел сказать что basket это не та корзина, та корзина это cart

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  я конечно не спорю но если не ошибаюсь то cart переводится телега а вот basket как раз то корзина ...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  вот перевод с bing.com : https://www.dropbox.com/s/qlkhbh2vtycxpxf/2019-01-27_122312.png

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shopping_cart

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я понимаю en мне вики не нужно

Answer (score 0):

Помогло использование  data атрибутов

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]